# UIButton not showing any effect when tapped?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am using Xcode 9.4.1 and I have added a UIButton in storyboard in a new project. Have changed the button to custom and have set constraints.

My problem is there is no change in button appearance when it is tapped. there has always been a default change in uibuttons appearance when it is tapped in earlier projects.

Is it only with me or its a general thing with new xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting UIButton's selected state properties.

Answer (score 1):

just check `state` of UIButton in Attributes Inspector set it `enable` then check `type` it should be `system` and not showing then once click on `drawing = Show touch bar on Highlight` then run your project and see when click is there any effect or not. Hope this is work fine for you.

Comment: type = .system works. By default I think it's custom when you create UIButton programmatically.